# How to allow Tomcat WAR app to write in folder

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, tomcat, debian, war

I'd like for my webapp which is deployed as a war `ROOT.war` to have write access to `/var/www/html/static/images` so that it can write uploaded and converted images to that folder so nginx can serve it statically. Currently it doesn't work and triggers a `java.nio.file.FileSystemException` exception together with the `Filesystem is read-only` message.

But the filesystem is not read-only and is in great condition. The folder has already been `chmod`ded `777`.

Extra info:
The tomcat setup is running on an Ubuntu 18.04 Azure VM with managed disk. The folder is residing on an Ext4 formatted drive

Comment: I had a similar problem and posted on ServerFault: [Application logging broken under Tomcat 9: permission denied to /var/log/myapp](https://serverfault.com/questions/989150/application-logging-broken-under-tomcat-9-permission-denied-to-var-log-myapp)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Let's start with: `chmod 777` is great for testing, but absolutely unfit for the real world and you shouldn't get used to this setting. Rather set the owner/group correctly, before you give world write permissions.

Edit: A similar question just came up on the Tomcat mailing list, and Emmanuel Bourg pointed out that **Debian Tomcat is sandboxed by systemd**. Read your [/usr/share/doc/tomcat9/README.Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/tomcat9/blob/master/debian/README.Debian) which contains this paragraph:

> Tomcat is sandboxed by systemd and only has write access to the
> following directories:
>
> - `/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/Catalina` (actually `/etc/tomcat9/Catalina`)
> - `/var/lib/tomcat9/logs`          (actually `/var/log/tomcat9`)
> - `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps`
> - `/var/lib/tomcat9/work`          (actually `/var/cache/tomcat9`)
>
> If write access to other directories is required the service settings
> have to be overridden. This is done by creating an `override.conf` file
> in `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d/` containing:
>
> > `[Service]`
> >
> > `ReadWritePaths=/path/to/the/directory/`
>
> The service has to be restarted afterward with:
>
> ```
>   systemctl daemon-reload
>   systemctl restart tomcat9
> ```

Edit 2022: Note that these are the 2019 paths - validate the file locations for later versions. From the comments to this answer (thank you to [V H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755637) and [Ng Sek Long)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463291/ng-sek-long) here are some updates:

> In current Ubuntu file is here: `sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat9.service` – V H Feb 26, 2022 at 19:55

> Mine (Ubuntu 20) is installed here `/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service` smh everybody use a different path. – Ng Sek Long Mar 28, 2022 at 8:36

End of edit, continuing with the passage that didn't solve OP's problem, but should stay in:

If - all things tested - Tomcat *should* have write access to that directory, but doesn't have it, the error message points me to an assumption: Could it be that

- Tomcat is running as root?
- The directory is mounted through NFS?

The default configuration for NFS is that root has no permissions whatsoever on that external filesystem (or was it no write-permission? this is ancient historical memory - look up "NFS root squash" to get the full story)

If this is a condition that matches what you are running, you should **stop running Tomcat as root**, and rather run it as an unprivileged user. Then you can set the permissions on the directory in question to be writeable by your tomcat-user, and readable by nginx, and you're done.

Running Tomcat as root is a recipe for disaster: You don't want a process that's available from the internet to run as root.

If these conditions don't meet your configuration: Elaborate on the configuration. I'd still stand by this description for others who might find this question/answer later.

Comment: See the additional paragraph for new wisdom straight from the Tomcat mailing list

Comment: Wonderful! This piece of information was really hard to find though. I've been looking everywhere for a solution and didn't even realize Systemd had MAC type of functionality like AppArmor (which I had disabled already as a possible solution).

Comment: @OlafKock You, the saviour! Thanks!

Comment: For whatever reason I can't find, this is not working for me. I even went ahead of myself and added a specific directory (that my app was supposed to create) after I changed the ownership to Tomcat. Then I changed the ownership of the dir and the User and Group for my personal user (which didn't even launched, by the way) but just no luck... of course, using root worked, but that is not a solution even if I trust the layers above my app enough. Gotta keep searching, I guess (This on Tomcat 9.0.31, Ubuntu server 20.04)

Comment: It's easier to use "systemctl edit tomcat9.service" to create the file "override.conf". There is no need to create the file directly.